# How to scale Enet (UDP)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, networking, udp, enet

The creator of enet told me that enet can handle 4000 connections per host, the OS won't be able to manage more than that. How to go above that?

If I use docker containers, they're still using the same OS right? So I haven't really solved anything or can I? Is a docker container considered as its own OS?

If I use EC2, I don't solve it either right? I'll be using one OS right? I'd like to try to solve this problem without having to buy multiple dedicated servers, is there anyway to do that? Using either cloud hosting or containers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll spawn an ec2 container at 3k programmatically, if anyone has a better solution let me know